# Userena raising RemovedInDjango19Warning

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-userena

I'm using userena app in my django project, when running `python manage.py migrate`, it just raise below warning:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/userena/utils.py:133:
>   RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.db.models.get_model is deprecated.
>   profile_mod = get_model(*settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE.rsplit('.', 1))
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/**init**.py:55:
>   RemovedInDjango19Warning: The utilities in django.db.models.loading
>   are deprecated in favor of the new application loading system.   from
>   . import loading

How to fix this issue?

BTW, I just find the latest build on github(https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena) is failing, so this project is no longer maintained?

Answer (score 0):

You can [open a pull request](https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/) on [userna's github repo](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena) or if it's difficult you can wait until the maintainers or other contributors will fix this and you have to update the package version.

There is a lot of similar warning from third party apps but it's better to help if possible.